# Need to show only DatePicker and Date MVC Grandnode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, nopcommerce

This is from Grandnode project.

I am trying to show only the datepicker, but it still showing both datepicker and timepicker.

I have created a model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]

public DateTime? DateUtc { get; set; }
```

And the partial view is as below

```
@Html.GrandEditorFor(x => x.DateUtc )
```

This still shows date and time and date picker and timepicker. I only want to show the date and the datepicker only.

Comment: Where is `@Html.GrandEditorFor` from?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider is from the partial view

Comment: Does it call `@Html.EditorFor` internally? If it does, you can attribute the property with `[UIHint("DateWithoutTime")]` and add an EditorTemplate `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateWithoutTime.cshtml` that only renders the datepicker without timepicker. [What are Display and Editor Templates?](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Yes and instead of [UIHint("DateWithoutTime")], I tried [UIHint("DateNullable")] because it only have DateNullable.cshtml and it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Desmond: Does this issue resolved?

Comment: @HinaKhuman Yes it resolved, sorry I have not answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

I have used `[UIHint("DateNullable")]` and it works.